# Is there any way to handle a button from a different activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

Referring to the image below. I want to update the map when the user clicks the View Map button. However, since this is part of an expandable list view, it is in it's own class, while the map itself is in another fragment activity.

Is there any way to listen to the button click and update the map accordingly from another activity?

Thanks!

[image]

Here's what i have so far. I tried getting the parameter via

```
ExpandableListElement.polyLinePass
```

but it does not give me anything back so i can't update the map. Also another question, does the map update itself when values are changed like the polyLine, or do I need to setup the map again?

Map Display Activity:

```
public class OfflineViewer extends FragmentActivity {
    private void setUpMap() {
        List<LatLng> listTemp = util.decodePoly(ExpandableListElement.polyLinePass);
    for(int l=0;l<listTemp.size() - 1;l++){
        list.add(listTemp.get(l));
        if(l==0) {              
        }
    }
        int listSize = list.size();
    //get polyline from expandable list elements
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        LatLng src = list.get(i);
        LatLng dest = list.get(i + 1);
        Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions() //mMap is the Map Object
        .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
        new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude))
        .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
    }
...
}
```

ExpandableListElement  Activity:

```
public class ExpandableListElement extends RelativeLayout {
        public ExpandableListElement(Context context, String routeName, String mode, String dist, String routeId, String start, String end, final String polyLine) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    setTextViewElements(routeName, mode, dist, routeId, start, end, polyLine);

    Button randButton = new Button(mContext);
    randButton.setText("View Map");
    randButton.setId(mIdPool);
    randButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        polyLinePass = polyLine;
        }
    });
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle that from your activity class. Lets say the map is in one fragment and the button in another on. They are both "hosted" by the same activity.

let your activity have a method like this and be sure it is public:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Fragment fragment1; //the frag with the button
    private Fragment fragment2; //the frag with the map

    public void updateMap(String argument) {
        if(fragment2 != null)
            fragment2.update(argument);
    }
}
```

then from the fragment with the button (fragment1), call ((MyActivity) getActivity()).updateMap(argument) to update your Map:

```
class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    // this is called on button click
    void onClick(...) {
        ((MyActivity) getActivity()).updateMap(argument)
    }
}
```

Your second fragment needs a public method for upting the map:

```
class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    public void updateMap(String arguments) {
        // update map...
    }
}
```

This strategy can also be used in lists

Comment: Hi @danijioo i tried what you suggested but i keep having this error in the OnClick method. `The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`

Comment: I made with work using, `((MyActivity) mContext).updateMap(mArgument);` thanks!